# Failure creating Access database from TFS 2010

Tags: ms-access, tfs, ms-access-2007, msscci

I have an Access database in source control on TFS that I need to pull down onto another machine (XP, Office 2007). I have the Team Foundation Server MSSCCI Provider 2010 installed and I can successfully see the source. However, when I try to have it created it fails, giving me this error:

> Failed to create a new database on a Team Foundation project.

Any idea what I've done wrong on this machine?

Comment: 8 questions, zero upvotes also.

Comment: Sorry guys, I went back and updated some questions from a while back. I'm also not familiar with what an upvote is, although now checking out the tooltips of what I assume would be an upvote icon, I can now see what they are. I wasn't aware of what those were before. I'll be sure to go back and update the answers to my questions to give credit where it's due :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the solution to this was that I had sent the database up to TFS from Access 2010, but was trying to pull it down to another machine with Access 2010. I thought the two versions shouldn't matter, but sending it up to TFS in Access 2007 and bringing it down in Access 2007 and Access 2010 appeared to work.